# How to use formatPercentage and renderDataTable together

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

I'd like to use `formatPercentage`,`rowname=FALSE` in renderDataTable. See below code Method 1 contains `formatPercentage` and Method 2 contains `rowname=FALSE`. I'd like to merge them together but keeps getting errors (`renderDataTable ignores ... arguments when expr yields a datatable object; see ?renderDataTable`). How do I do this?

Method 1 contains `formatPercentage` but can't pass renderDataTable options:

```
# Method 1 format Percentage 
output$funddetails <- DT::renderDataTable(
      DT::datatable({
      heatmap_raw[heatmap_raw$Keeper%in%
                    input$selectkeeper&month(heatmap_raw$period)%in%
                    input$selectmonth,c("apid","Fund Name","Status","Comments","Last Update by Keeper","Most Recent Portfolio")]
      })%>%formatPercentage(1, 2)
)
```

Method 2 only contains options for renderDataTable but I can't use formatPercentage:

```
#Method 2
data_fund <- reactive({
    heatmap_raw[heatmap_raw$Keeper%in%
        input$selectkeeper&month(heatmap_raw$period)%in%
        input$selectmonth,c("apid","Fund Name","Status","Comments","Last Update by Keeper","Most Recent Portfolio")]
})

output$funddetails <- DT::renderDataTable(
  data_fund(),
  rowname=FALSE,
  options = list(
    pageLength=10,
    #autoWidth = TRUE,
    lengthMenu = list(c(25, 50, -1), c('25', '50', 'All')),
    searchHighlight = TRUE,
    scrollX=TRUE
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem with method 1 is due to the position of the curly brackets of the datatable command. You don't need them actually. Here is an example that should work for you:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      datatable(iris, 
                rowname=FALSE,
                options = list(
                  pageLength=10,
                  #autoWidth = TRUE,
                  lengthMenu = list(c(25, 50, -1), c('25', '50', 'All')),
                  searchHighlight = TRUE,
                  scrollX=TRUE)
      ) %>% formatPercentage(1, 2)
    )
  }
)
```